# what is the theory behind matlab butter function?

Tags: matlab, filters

I would like to know the theory behind matlab butter function. Is there any book which gives clear idea on how it works. In future I would like to calculate the coefficients manually.

Comment: it would be painful, but i might be able to write a little primer on the theory of the Butterworth filter.  maybe limit it to low-pass.  Butterworth filters are *"maximally flat"* in both passband and stopband.  this means that in the magnitude frequency response as many derivatives are zero at a frequency of zero (DC).  this stuff is in textbooks and maybe some online resource.  i wonder if Julius Smith has a good detailed treatment.

Answer (score 2):

The MATLAB function that you refer to uses this knowledge to calculate the coefficients

Briefly, the function you refer to goes something like this:

- The [transfer functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Normalized_Butterworth_polynomials) for analog Butterworth filters of any order are already known analytically. It selects the normalized transfer function polynomial for the order you select.
- The normalized polynomial is scaled appropriately according to the desired cutoff frequency, giving an $s$-domain transfer function that has the response that you want.
- The $s$-domain prototype filter is then mapped to a discrete-time approximation using the [bilinear transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform). This is the most commonly-used method of mapping a continuous-time filter to a discrete-time filter.
- The result of the bilinear transform is a transfer function in the $z$-domain, from which the filter coefficients are easily found by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

For a manually calculation of the coefficients of the IIR-Filter, the Jave speech toolkit has a open source implementation of it.

See [Butterworth.java](https://github.com/sikoried/jstk/blob/master/jstk/src/de/fau/cs/jstk/sampled/filters/Butterworth.java) for calculating the coefficients and [IIRFilter.java](https://github.com/sikoried/jstk/blob/master/jstk/src/de/fau/cs/jstk/sampled/filters/IIRFilter.java) how they are applied on a signal.

Here are additional functions to calculate frequency response, amplitude response and phase response of an arbitary IIR-Filter:

```
public double amplitudeResponse(final double omega) {
    return ComplexNumber.magnitude(frequencyResponse(omega));
}

public double phaseResponse(final double omega) {
    return ComplexNumber.toEulerPhi(frequencyResponse(omega));
}

private double[] frequencyResponse(final double omega) {
    // z = exp(-j*omega);
    final double[] z = new double[2];
    z[0] = Math.cos(omega);
    z[1] = Math.sin(omega);

    final double[] h = transferFunction(z);
    return h;
}

private @NonNull double[] transferFunction(final double @NonNull [] z) {
    final double[] tmp = new double[2];
    final double[] zp = new double[2];

    final double[] numerator = new double[2];
    numerator[0] = 0;
    numerator[1] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        ComplexNumber.power(z, -k, zp);
        ComplexNumber.multiply(b[k], zp, tmp);
        ComplexNumber.add(numerator, tmp, numerator);
    }

    final double[] denominator = new double[2];
    denominator[0] = 0;
    denominator[1] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        ComplexNumber.power(z, -k, zp);
        ComplexNumber.multiply(a[k], zp, tmp);
        ComplexNumber.add(denominator, tmp, denominator);
    }

    final double[] resesult = new double[2];
    ComplexNumber.divide(numerator, denominator, resesult);
    return resesult;
}
```

And here are additional unit tests to make it clear how the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are used.

```
@Test
public void testFilterWithOrderTwoFilter() {
    final float[] x = new float[] { 2f, -3f, 0f, 2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f };
    final double[] b = new double[] { 0.6, 0.4 };
    final double[] a = new double[] { 1.0, 0.5, 0.8 };
    final float[] expectedY = new float[] { 1.2f, -1.6f, -1.36f, 3.16f,
            0.308f, -2.682f, 1.0946f, 1.5983f };

    final float[] actualY = new float[8];
    final IIRFilter filter = new IIRFilter(b, a);
    filter.filter(x, actualY);
    assertArrayEquals(expectedY, actualY, COMPARISON_DELTA);
}
```

And these unit tests I've used to test against the octave signal package:

```
@Test
public void testCalcNormalizedFrequency() {
    assertEquals(0.0, calcNormalizedFrequency(0, 44100), COMPARISON_DELTA);
    assertEquals(0.5, calcNormalizedFrequency(44100 / 4, 44100),
            COMPARISON_DELTA);
    // Nyquist
    assertEquals(1.0, calcNormalizedFrequency(44100 / 2, 44100),
            COMPARISON_DELTA);
}

@Test
public void testCreateLowPass() {
    // order 3, cutoff 0.2
    //@formatter:off
    final double[] bExpected = new double[] {
            0.018099, 0.054297, 0.054297, 0.018099 };
    final double[] aExpected = new double[] {
            1.00000, -1.76004, 1.18289, -0.27806 };
    //@formatter:off
    final IIRFilter filter = createLowPass(3, 0.2);
    final double[] bActual = filter.getFeedforwardCoefficients(false);
    final double[] aActual = filter.getFeedbackCoefficients(false);
    assertArrayEquals(bExpected, bActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
    assertArrayEquals(aExpected, aActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
}

@Test
public void testCreateHighPass() {
    // order 3, cutoff 0.2
    //@formatter:off
    final double[] bExpected = new double[] {
            0.52762, -1.58287, 1.58287, -0.52762 };
    final double[] aExpected = new double[] {
            1.00000, -1.76004, 1.18289, -0.27806 };
    //@formatter:off
    final IIRFilter filter = createHighPass(3, 0.2);
    final double[] bActual = filter.getFeedforwardCoefficients(false);
    final double[] aActual = filter.getFeedbackCoefficients(false);
    assertArrayEquals(bExpected, bActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
    assertArrayEquals(aExpected, aActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
}

@Test
public void testCreateBandPass() {
    // order 3, cutoffLow 0.2, cutoffHigh 0.7
    //@formatter:off
    final double[] bExpected = new double[] {
            0.16667, 0.00000, -0.50000, 0.00000, 0.50000, 0.00000, -0.16667};
    final double[] aExpected = new double[] {
            1.0000e+000, -6.6370e-001, 1.6314e-001, -1.6192e-001,
            3.6596e-001, -7.3744e-002, 1.6374e-017 };
    //@formatter:off
    final IIRFilter filter = createBandPass(3, 0.2, 0.7);
    final double[] bActual = filter.getFeedforwardCoefficients(false);
    final double[] aActual = filter.getFeedbackCoefficients(false);
    assertArrayEquals(bExpected, bActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
    assertArrayEquals(aExpected, aActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
}

@Test
public void testCreateBandReject() {
    // order 3, cutoffLow 0.2, cutoffHigh 0.7
    //@formatter:off
    final double[] bExpected = new double[] {
            0.16667, -0.22123, 0.59789, -0.45690, 0.59789, -0.22123, 0.16667 };
    final double[] aExpected = new double[] {
            1.0000e+000, -6.6370e-001, 1.6314e-001, -1.6192e-001,
            3.6596e-001, -7.3744e-002, 1.6374e-017 };
    //@formatter:off
    final IIRFilter filter = createBandReject(3, 0.2, 0.7);
    final double[] bActual = filter.getFeedforwardCoefficients(false);
    final double[] aActual = filter.getFeedbackCoefficients(false);
    assertArrayEquals(bExpected, bActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
    assertArrayEquals(aExpected, aActual, COMPARISON_DELTA);
}
```

Comment: lotta (potentially very useful) code.  less theory.  but the code does answer the OP's wish to calculate "manually".